# Windows search not showing file content results from mapped DFS drive

Tags: windows, network-share, dfs, search

I already checked the thread Windows 7 search not showing results from mapped Server 2008 R2 BUT my case is different:
We have file servers (2012 R2) and Windows 7 workstations.
The mapped network drive is from a DFS namespace.
When I search from the mapped drive on the workstation I get only the file name matches and an option to search in file contents. When clicking on that it takes ages and anyhow doesn't return all full text matches. On the server I don't have an option "file content".
When I search on the server directly the logical drive or mount the server share (\servername\share) on the workstation, I then get all matches including the full text.
Here two screenshots from the workstation. The first is the DFS mount, the second the direct server mount. Please note the difference in the file types.
[DFS namespace share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI4fM.png)
[Server share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueQCx.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK, to answer my own question: there is no problem with server or computer configurations. The issue is by design, as windows search doesn't support UNC paths with DFS roots.
As per this site (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744693(WS.10).aspx)
Windows Search works well on a single share departmental server with the following characteristics: [truncated] Users directly access the server. That is, the server is not made available through Distributed File System (DFS).